# Berkeley mathematics department colloquium by S.Mochizuki

Tags: nt.number-theory, abc-conjecture

On the website of the Berkeley mathematics department there is mention ([see this](https://events.berkeley.edu/index.php/calendar/sn/math.html?event_ID=133775)) of a colloquium  held on november 5, 2020 (by Zoom) whose speaker was Shinichi Mochizuki, with a talk titled "Classical Roots of Inter-universal Teichmüller Theory". The corresponding slides seem to be online ([see this](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Emotizuki/2020-11%20Classical%20roots%20of%20IUT.pdf)). Here are my factual questions:

1. did this event really occur ?
2. if yes to 1, how was the speaker introduced ?
3. if yes to 1, do the slides reflect all that was said, or were there other comments, and if so what ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the motivation for asking (2)?

Comment: The motivation for asking (1) also seems fairly unclear. I doubt the Berkeley mathematics department has a habit of inventing fictitious events.

Comment: The motivation for asking is (1) is that there is some controversy regarding the acceptance of the 4 papers of S.Mochizuki claiming a proof of the abc conjecture, and some talks around this have been canceled in the past. Regarding (2) I was wondering if the introduction would be factual or would mention the aforementioned 4 papers. It must be stressed that the colloquium chair is Ken Ribet, see this https://math.berkeley.edu/about/events/colloquium

Comment: I heard once about Hirzebruch introducing Wiles at ICM, maybe 1994, and it included something such as "... and possible applications to number theory".

Comment: "It must be stressed"!

Comment: @Arthur it's possible there was a last-minute cancellation.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

1. Yes it really occurred.
2. He was introduced in the normal way, something like "Today we have Shinichi Mochizuki..." that mentioned his name, maybe his talk title and the institution he's from (can't remember exactly.)
3. He annotated those slides with a magnificent glitter-rainbow-colored pen, adding clarificatory details here and there. But yes, (to my understanding) those notes describe the content of what was said.

Comment: +1 for "magnificent glitter-rainbow-colored pen"

Comment: Was it recorded?

Comment: @DavidRoberts No, it wasn't recorded

Comment: Makes sense. It's not like there's a real pressing need for him to communicate this work or anything.... /s

Comment: @DavidRoberts He said that he was planning to record the talk at a later point and upload it to Youtube.

Comment: @CarlosEsparza oh, that is good.